# missing messange in view using connect-flash

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, connect-flash

I was using this code from this repo : https://github.com/eldyvoon/register-login-nodejs but I can't see the error message in view although the author is using connect-flash to handle the error. When u login with wrong credential for example the message should appear in the view. Anyone can help here? debug for hours couldn't get the solution.

Comment: Please try to refresh you browser

Comment: @BlackMamba what does that means? I try to debug, the flow is correct, but the author someone missed something, the error doesn't appear.